# Parse a fasta file using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, mysqli, fasta

I have a fasta file **input.fa** which looks like this:

```
>KJH325_Org_name_strain
ANNTTHWQLPMCVREEDFSC
>IJA254.1_Org_name
HITYYPQLKSSCMART
>ASDL658_Org_name_str
TTILPQWYERSAASMNCFGHDKLCC
and so on.
```

I want to enter these short sequences into a Mysql table using PHP such that the `KJH325`(i.e., the ID after the first underscore '_') goes into ID column and the rest `Org_name or Org_name_strain` goes into the orgname column and the short sequence in the next line goes into sequence column.
I have tried this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "shortseqdb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n\n";

$fasta_file = 'input.fa';
$header='';
$id = '';
$org_name = '';

$lines = file($fasta_file) or die("Unable to open file!");

foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $header = strpos($line, '>'); <---- UPDATED
   if ($header!==false) {
      $key = trim(substr($line, 0, $header));
      $value = trim(substr($line, $header+1));
        list($id, $org_name) = explode("_",$key);


            $sql = "INSERT INTO `seqs` (`ID`, `org_name`, `sequence`) VALUES ($id, $org_name, $value)";
    }
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Values inserted successfully in the table seqs\n";
} else {
    echo "Error inserting values: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

It connects successfully but I am getting the following error:

> Connected successfully
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 26
>
> Error inserting values: No database selected

Could anybody help me where is this script wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but still showing the same error.

Comment: Read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: @PHPglue thanks, I tried selecting the database using a function 'mysql_select_db(connection,dbname)' and now I am getting this error: "Connected successfully 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 15"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was in username and password. I looked into the privileges on XAMPP in the same database and it turned out I had to specify the username and password as well.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "shortseqdb";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n\n";
// select a db
mysqli_select_db($conn,"shortseqdb") or die("Could not select the specified database");
```

And used `mysqli_db_connect($connect,dbname)` to select the specified database. Then it worked perfectly.

Thanks for your comments.